# share image on twitter Using FHSTwitterEngine in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to share Image on Twitter But When I use FHSTwitterEngine than image only send only one account which is login.How I can share image to all twitter account?

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: - (IBAction)shareImageBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.jpg"];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6);
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:@"Image" withImageData:imgData];
}

Comment: See this one Example : https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/TwitterPost

Comment: FHSTwitterEngine Have already method to share image.

Comment: Using this, the image posted only login account but i want to share image all twitter accounts.

Comment: if there is another way to share image on all twitter account , please help me...

Comment: thanks we have done